# Why are my speakers so quiet?

Tags: speakers

I have just installed 15.04 onto my 2011 iMac with the stock i5-2400s and AMD Radeon graphics card. The built in speakers play media with normal volume, but when I plug in my insignia stereo speakers I can barely hear sound with everything set to full volume.

Comment: Have you tried going into sound settings and enabling "Allow volume over 100%"?  That usually helps with stuff like this.